# Get file name in express request stream

Tags: node.js, express

Im wondering if is posible to know what is the file name of an incomming binary request.

This is my situation I have this code that handles the file upload

```
router.route('/:filename')
.put(function(req,res){   
                var uuid = guid();
                var fileExtension = req.params.filename.substring(req.params.filename.lastIndexOf("."));
                if(!fs.existsSync('../files')){
                    fs.mkdirSync('../files')
                }

                var newFile = fs.createWriteStream('../files/'+uuid+fileExtension);     

                req.pipe(newFile);  

                req.on('end',function(end){             
                    console.log("Finished")
                    res.send(uuid+fileExtension)                                
                })
})
```

as you can see now ,I need the file name specified in the URL`('/:filename')`. My question is: If it is possible to take that attribute from the resquest stream, instead the url or a form key?

Comment: This is really dependant on the type of middleware you are using to handle the upload?

Comment: Hi @James I'm Using just node streams. I pipe the request stram into  an write stream object. as you can see in my posted code: req.pipe(newFile);

Comment: Which version of express are you using?

Comment: @James I'm using the version  4.15.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to inspect the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header of the request and parse the file name information out if processing the HTTP request manually.

However, I'd recommend you look at some of the existing file upload middlewares, no point in reinventing the wheel

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy)
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)
- [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty)
- [pez](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pez)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) middleware you can access the uploaded filename like so

```
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer()
router.route('/:filename')
  .put(upload.single('fileField'),function(req,res){   

    var fileName = req.file.originalname

    var uuid = guid();
    var fileExtension = req.params.filename.substring(req.params.filename.lastIndexOf("."));
    if(!fs.existsSync('../files')){
      fs.mkdirSync('../files')
    }

    var newFile = fs.createWriteStream('../files/'+uuid+fileExtension);     

    req.pipe(newFile);  

    req.on('end',function(end){             
      console.log("Finished")
      res.send(uuid+fileExtension)                                
    })
})
```